# inline code doesn't work on a asp:Button

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

Could someone tell me why this is happening and how to fix it if possible?

I have a button in a aspx file like:

```
<% foreach blah %.

orderID = GenerateCorrectOrderID();

    <input id="btnOrder"  type="button" style="background-color: #000040; color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: normal" value="Order" onclick="javascript:OpenOrderService('<%=orderID%>','A');" />


<% end foreach blah %>
```

The orderID is being placed correctly in the html as expected.
I would like to replace the input button with a asp.button like this:

```
                    <asp:Button ID="btnOrder"  style="background-color: #000040; color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: normal" Text="Order"    OnClick="UpdateOrderGrid" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" Visible="False"  onclientclick="javascript:OpenOrderService('<%=#orderID%>','A');"  />
```

The <%=#orderID%> is not being properly placed in the html file.  In fact it looks just like this: <%=#orderID%>   How can I force it to inline properly?

Any idea on how I can get this to work?
I really want to use a Asp.Button because I have a trigger in a update panel that it is attached to.

Comment: Do you have the runat="server" on your button?

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I would use a repeater and databind the onclientclick instead of putting the code in your aspx/ascx file.

If you MUST do it this way, it appears you've mixed databinding syntax with inline evaluation syntax.

What I think you want is

```
... onclinentclick="javascript:OpenOrderService('<%= orderId %>','A');" />
```

Comment: I basically inherited this project....and I need to do a small fix rather than do a massive overhaul on this page.  That code you wrote is the part that doesn't work.  Inlines do not seem to work properly when it comes to asp.buttons.   (I have tried doing it without the # and it still doesn't work.)

Comment: Now I remember, you can't do this because the <Asp: controls get processed prior to the <%=

You are really left with either using a repeater and databinding or sticking with the <input type=button

Answer (score 0):

Well after trying several different ways like with java script classes and what not....I decided to use a input button which I could use some inline code to define it's id.  I then put a asp.button inside a invisible div and then when the input button was pushed I would call the click event of the asp.button which in turn would cause the trigger of the update panel to fire off.

I know this is a very ugly way to do it but I spent way too much time looking for a more elegant way to accomplish this.